# TNS listner error while connection oracle form 10g to oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g, oracleforms

I am running oracle 11g and i am trying to connect form/reports 10 with it and i get TNS listener error. i can connect to oracle 11g DB using PHP, SQLPLUS and SQLDEVELOPER. I am running oracle 11g and reports/form 10g on the same windows 7 machine.

error details

```
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested i connect descriptor.
```

listener.log data

```
Sun Apr 21 21:05:44 2013
21-APR-2013 21:05:44 * service_update * orcle * 0
Sun Apr 21 21:05:57 2013
21-APR-2013 21:05:56 * service_update * orcle * 0
21-APR-2013 21:06:06 * service_update * orcle * 0
Sun Apr 21 21:06:24 2013
21-APR-2013 21:06:23 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)(SID=orcl)   (CID=(PROGRAM=G:\app\form10g\BIN\frmbld.exe)(HOST=APML-HP)(USER=APML))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=49519)) * establish * orcl * 12514
TNS-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
Sun Apr 21 21:06:39 2013
21-APR-2013 21:06:39 * service_update * orcle * 0
21-APR-2013 21:06:45 * service_update * orcle * 0
```

Comment: we can't help you if you don't state what is the error

Comment: previously i tried to add these details but got the message that my question does not meet standard of stackoverflow. so it is edited now

Comment: can you post the output of "lsnrctl services" ?

Comment: Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1522)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "orcl" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:10 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER

Comment: Service "orcleXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcle", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "D000" established:0 refused:0 current:0 max:1022 state:ready
         DISPATCHER <machine: APML-HP, pid: 2136>
         (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=APML-HP)(PORT=49165))
The command completed successfully

Comment: Your listener supports the orcle service and you seem to connect using the orcl service name. (or is this a typo in the question?)

Comment: it is a typo, and orcle also does not connect, and orcl is connected when i try connecting using sqlplus or php, only form/reports give this error

Comment: i have finally installed oracle 10 XE to solve this problem, can some one tell me how to close this question?